# Renaming Windows XP computer

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, rename

I am running a Windows XP VirtualBox Virtual machine, but get the following error:

```
The following error occurred attempting to rename the computer to "VM1":
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

I am logged in as local administrator and when prompted for credentials, used my local administrator credentials.

I would need to rename this VM as it's a copy of another VM with the same name.  How can I rename it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start VirtualBox Manager then select the VM and click settings. Under General tab, you can change the name. After the VM has been created, the name is only a label (identifier). The name will still be associated with the correct VM when altered.

Comment: I have changed that.  Just wanting to know if multiple Virtual boxes with the same Windows name (but different name as you mentioned) on the same network would be OK.

Comment: If you mean the same OS but different labels, then it is possible. I have three Windows XP VMs but different labels. The VirtualBox Manager does not permit the same labels.